# How do i use the android content provider api of the chrome browser?

Tags: android, android-chrome

After reading about android content provider framework, I can guess that the URI for the chrome content provider would be something like this `content://com.example.chrome.ContentProvider/DataType/data_id`. I want to list out the links visited in the chrome browser as they occur from my app. I didn't get any standard Manual Page for the android chrome browser content provider API, after searching online. Could you point me to some man pages or/and examples of the same. Please comment if any more context is needed, Thanks.

update:
Ok so after some reading, I was able to list exposed apis for chrome and firefox, and then I tried to put a
`getContentResolver().query(...)` in the main_activity.java
and `android:name="org.mozilla.firefox.permissions.SEARCHHISTORY_PROVIDER"`permissions in the manifest file. But the app failed to open. I understand that the firefox browser app is denying access to my app as its signature is not verified. Could you shed some light on the signature verification process and how do i sign my app with a valid signature for it to access the firefox api?

Comment: You know that your app can list all providers available on your device? Use it to find those of chrome.

Comment: Yes that's helpful, but I meant information on using the chrome content provider i.e the parameters I need to pass for different content queries. Some examples on it if possible.

Comment: Are you shure that what you want is possible?

Comment: It should be if chrome has an exposed content provider api, and a query set which includes querying url hit requests. I am not sure that's why I am asking on this forum. If anyone knows about this topic then kindly share some Instructions. Thanks.

Comment: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/4e9123c39129f134e0bd2cb793cbd372cc0baf31/chrome/android/java/src/org/chromium/chrome/browser/ChromeBrowserProvider.java